# react router v4 nested routes conflicting with wildcard route

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I have an app where you can access a user's profile via /someusername
Now I'm trying to simplfy a /self dashboard component where one could goto /self/test or /self/something else but that is conflicting with the user route which is /:username. how do I fix this?

```
function Self({ match }) {
    return (
        <main> 
            <aside>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/test`}>Friends</Link>
            </aside>
            <article>
                <section>
                    <Route path={`${match.path}/:tab`} component={Test} />
                </section>
            </article>
        </main>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>             
                    <Route path="/self" exact={true} component={Self} />
                    <Route path="/:username" component={User} />  
                </Switch>
            </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the Routes in a `<Switch></Switch>`. Then place the routes in an order, where the one that you want to match first comes first.

Comment: I've updated it with Switch, but the issue still happens as the Route for /self is exact but the nested one for /self/:tab is not and it leaks into the /:id wildcard